# Linear Regression when we have mix of variables

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance

I have a regression problem where predictors are mix of integers and probability values. The dependent variable is in $[0,1]$. For example,

```
feature_1 = 2 [is a discrete value]
feature_2 = 54 [is a discrete value]
feature_3 =0.8 [between 0 and 1]
feature_4 = 0.3 [between 0 and 1]
target = 0.255 [between 0 and 1]
```

I have tried standardization and normalizing i.e. subtract each feature value by its mean and divide by standard deviation. But some of the regression coefficients are negative and all the coefficients are less than $1$, such as  $(0.23, -0.74, 0.23, 0.34)$.
Is the procedure correct?

Comment: Please consider implementing logistic regression since your dependent variable is between 0 and 1. There are unlikely to be serious problems with using discrete/continuous predictors.

Comment: Did you want to say that all your coefficients are less than 1?

Comment: OLS regression is not scale invariant. You may want to consider reverting to a finite mixture model which is.

Comment: Why the values of coefficients are a problem for you? You don’t need to normalize of standardize variables for linear regression. I see no problem in here, unless you omitted some context that helps to explain why would that be considered as incorrect?

Comment: Consider using a beta regression model since the target lies between 0 and 1.  There is no need to standardize either the target or the features.

Comment: My feature_1 and feature_2 are basically "distance" so are numeric integer values. And my feature_3 and fetaure_4 are probabilities. So, to mitigate this scale difference, I standardised my data.

Comment: @Ale Yes all coefficients are less than 1. Do, I need to standardize the target variable as well?